# Is it possible to remove Windows 7 from dual-boot?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, dual-boot, grub2

I have Windows 7 as primary OS with Linux Mint as secondary OS. I am just feeling comfortable with Linux and want to remove Windows from the disk.

Is it possible to remove it without damaging data?

Should I keep the disk partitions the same (C, D ,E, F, Linux Mint partition) and will that hurt Linux performance ?

Linux is on 100GB partition at the end of Disk (with LVM), should I move it to primary partition ?

How to handle the GRUB ?

Any other thoughtful suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GParted to remove the drive on which Windows 7 is installed, usually it is the C drive, the other drives used in the Windows install can be removed as well and repurposed to store new data.

There should be no palpable decrease in performance of your Linux by removing Windows.

The next thing you will encounter is GRUB, it will still have the Windows entry in it. Refer to this thread to remove that entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi

Answer (score 0):

You can resize partitions with **gparted**. Be careful to change partition order.